# Jest.useFakeTimers times out when using MUI v5 DesktopDatePicker

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, datepicker

When trying to run tests with MUI-X v5 DesktopDatePicker, I would like to use Jest useFakeTimers to set the system time that will allow me to test selecting dates with running into issues using `new Date()` and next months (as I have past selections disabled). When setting `jest.useFakeTimers()` my test timeout. Is there a solution for this?